# Python inheritance: Raising an error when non-overridden methods are called

Tags: python, inheritance

I am writing a subclass of `dict` that maps from string keys to values of arbitrary types. If a key is a regex, it is stored and queried separately.

```
class RegexDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # non-regex keys in the parent class
        self.regex_dict = {}  # regex keys in the child class

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            for x in self.regex_dict:
                if re.fullmatch(x, key):
                    return self.regex_dict[x]
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key, is_regex = key
        if is_regex:
            self.regex_dict[key] = value
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

Because this class will be used by other libraries (which is why I have to use inheritance), I want to make sure that an error is raised when non-overridden methods in the base class are called. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inherit from [`collections.abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) instead of dict.

It will fill in the gaps automatically, and also let you know which things you have to implement.

In addition to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, you’ll also have to implement `__delitem__`, `__iter__` and `__len_`. If you can’t implement those reasonably, you can raise e.g. `NotImplementedError` from them (even though that will limit the use of your class a lot).

This will have the advantage that all dict methods which only need `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (+ what you implement) internally will work out of the box.

Comment: Sadly, from my experience, inheriting *MutableMapping* is not enough for many libs, even for mainstream like *pandas*. Additionally, those methods working out of the box seem to be in contrary to OPs needs.

Comment: This is indeed the ideal case, but I do need to make the class work with `pandas`. Internally, `pandas` calls `np.dtype()`, which is unfortunately not compatible with custom types.

Answer (score -1):

Don't subclass. To convince third-party libs that your object is a *dict*, set `__class__` attribute.

```
class RegexDict():
    __class__ = dict

    def __init__(self):
        self.non_regex_dict = {}
        self.regex_dict = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.non_regex_dict[key]
        except KeyError:
            for x in self.regex_dict:
                if re.fullmatch(x, key):
                    return self.regex_dict[x]
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key, is_regex = key
        if is_regex:
            self.regex_dict[key] = value
        else:
            self.non_regex_dict[key] = value

rd = RegexDict()
print(isinstance(rd, dict))
rd.clear()
```

output:

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libo.py", line 30, in <module>
    rd.clear()
AttributeError: 'RegexDict' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

Comment: This solution did not work with `pandas` on my machine. It failed when `pandas` called `np.dtype()` with a `RegexDict` instance. I'm interested in why this didn't work but inheritance did, but I wan't able to find `np.dtype()` in the Numpy source code.

Comment: @LiboYin Could you provide an example? Please edit your question.